# How to react to ASP.NET MVC WebGrid paging to reattach row click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

Inside my `Index.cshtml` page there is a `<div id="searchResults"></div>` which I fill with a partial view (containing only a `WebGrid`) on a form submit by calling `$.ajax` with `cache: false` (this is what the function `loadWithoutCaching` does). There I also register handlers to react to hover and clicking on rows inside the `WebGrid`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function () {
    var model = $(this).serialize();
    $("#searchResults").loadWithoutCaching(
      "/LogSearch/SearchResults",
      model,
      function () {
        $("#accSearchCriteria").accordion("option", "active", false);
        $("#accSearchResults").accordion("option", "active", 0);

        registerRowEvents();
      });
    return false;
  })
})

function registerRowEvents() {
  $("#grdResults tbody tr").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("clickable");
  }).on("click", function () {
    alert("bing");
  })
}
```

The problem: I use paging in the `WebGrid`, and after I switch the page for the first time, I don't react to hover or click on a row anymore. I understand that these event handlers are lost, but how (or rather, when) can I reattach them?

When this part of my website is reloaded via paging (it goes into the action method in the controller to get its data again by itself), there is no other `$(document).ready` again. Is there anything similar that I can use?
I tried `onload` and others on the `div` containing the `WebGrid`, but that didn't work either.

I also tried reacting to clicks on the `a` elements triggering the paging, but that is too early. I have to catch the time **after** the grid is finished with the paging and the reattach my code to handle hover and click. How can I do this; or is there a better approach?

**Edit:** I found `$(document).ajaxComplete(fn)` which is triggered when the grid is reloaded. Now all that's left is to find out *what* triggered the event, that is, which `<div>` in the website is loaded, as there are more than one. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if it help for you.please use the event delegation this basically adds a click event listener for the current and future elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    App.initEvents();
  $("form").submit(function () {
    var model = $(this).serialize();
    $("#searchResults").loadWithoutCaching(
      "/LogSearch/SearchResults",
      model,
      function () {
        $("#accSearchCriteria").accordion("option", "active", false);
        $("#accSearchResults").accordion("option", "active", 0);
        });
    return false;
  });

});

var App={
initEvents:function(){
    $(document).on("hover","#grdResults tbody tr",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("clickable");
    });

  $(document).on("click","#grdResults tbody tr",function(){
  alert("bing");
  });

}
};
```